# Ошибка в сравнении переменных int

Tags: java, строки, intellij-idea

Данная программа является игрой в рулетку,
  В этом блоке игрок выбирает на что ставит, на `int`  или на  `string`.
Выбор игрока определит `int number1` или `string stavka`.

```
 System.out.println("Сделайте вашу ставку. Вы можете поставить на Красное 
 или Черное, на Четное или Нечетное.");
            if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                int number1 = scanner.nextInt();}
           else if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String stavka = scanner.next();
```

Проблема в том что в строке где `int number1` сравнивается с рандомным числом `int number`, выдает ошибку number1 "Cannot resolve symbol 'number1"

```
 else if(number1==number);
 import java.io.UTFDataFormatException;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Random;
 public class Bender {

static boolean playAgain = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (playAgain) {
        Game();
    }
}
public static void Game() {
    String[] colors = {"Черное", "Красное"};
    String[] parity = {"Четное", "Нечетное"};
    int allmoney;
    Random random = new Random();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("Добро пожаловать в игру Рулетка!");
    System.out.print("Введите сумму с которой вы хотите начать игру:");
    allmoney = scanner.nextInt();
    boolean isPlaying = true;
    while (isPlaying) {
        System.out.println("Сделайте вашу ставку. Вы можете поставить на Красное или Черное, на Четное или Нечетное.");
            if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                int number1 = scanner.nextInt();}
           else if (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String stavka = scanner.next();

            System.out.println("Какую сумму ставите?");
            int summa = scanner.nextInt();
            if (summa > allmoney) {
                System.out.println("У вас не хватает денег для этой ставки.");
                break;
            }
            int colorIndex = random.nextInt(colors.length);
            int number = random.nextInt(36);
            System.out.println("Выпало " + parity[number % 2] + " " + number + " " + colors[colorIndex]);
            if (stavka.equals(colors[colorIndex]) || stavka.equals(parity[number % 2])) {
                System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили! Выигрыш составляет: " + summa * 2);
                allmoney = allmoney + summa * 2;
                System.out.println("Ваши деньги на данный момент составляют: " + allmoney);}
           else if(number1==number);
                System.out.println("Ставка сыграла, вы победили! Выигрыш составляет: " + summa * 2);
                allmoney = allmoney + summa * 15;
                System.out.println("Ваши деньги на данный момент составляют: " + allmoney);}

            else {
                System.out.println("Вы проиграли");
                allmoney = allmoney - allmoney/2;
                System.out.println("Ваши деньги на данный момент составляют: " + allmoney);
            }
            if (allmoney <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Недостаточно денег для продолжения игры!");
                isPlaying = false;
                playAgain = false;

            } else System.out.println("Делаем ставку еще раз?");
            String otvet = scanner.next();
            if (otvet.equals("Да")) {
                System.out.println("Продолжаем!");
                isPlaying = true;
                playAgain = true;
            } else if (otvet.equals("Нет")) {
                isPlaying = false;
                playAgain = false;
                System.out.println("Жаль. До встречи!");
                System.out.println("Ваш капитал: " + allmoney);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Собственно, вопрос в чём?

Comment: Это игра рулетка, игрок может ставить на цвет, четность, или определенное число, как реализовать возможность ставки на цвет и четность я знаю, как сделать так что бы игрок мог ставить и на значение int я не знаю

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь в строку (**String**) сохранить целое число (**int**)

Если вам необходимо считать **целое число** и сохранить в **String** используйте **Integer.toString()** чтобы привести **Integer** к **String**

```
String i = Integer.toString(scanner.nextInt());
```

Вот небольшой пример, который показывает как считывать числа:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // создаём объект класса Scanner
    if(scanner.hasNextInt()) {                // если с потока можно считать целое число
        int i = scanner.nextInt();            // считываем целое число и сохраняем в i
        System.out.println("Число " + i);
    } else {                                  //иначе
        String s = scanner.next();            //считываем строку и сохраняем в s
        System.out.println("Строка " + s);
    }       
    scanner.close();
```

Comment: Попробовал данный вариант, к сожелению не работает, не знаю в чем причина, если есть возможность, протестируйте в  IDE и дайте знать, спасибо.

Comment: Я это писал и запускал в IDE, работает. Когда запускаете программу в консоли можно написать число, либо строку, программа отреагирует сообщением

Comment: скопируйте этот код в метод main() и импортируйте все что укажет IDE

Comment: Вот пример кода.string stavka передаеться в строку if (stavka.equals(colors[colorIndex]) || stavka.equals(parity[number % 2] || number1.equals[number])) { А значение int number1 не передаеться P.S Полный код вверху

Comment: @Roman, `number1` у вас создана в блоке `if` и только там и видна. Создайте переменную `number1` в соответствующей области видимости.

Comment: Пробовал не помогло, тогда number1 не инициализирует